# Angular2 interface on @input not working with AoT

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-aot

I have an interface:

```
export interface IEvent {
    name: string;
    city: string;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
}
```

Which I use in my class:

```
import {IEvent} from '../../interfaces/IEvent';

export class Event implements OnInit {

    @Input() data: IEvent;
```

When compiling with AoT I get this error:

`Module src/interfaces/IEvent.ts does not export IEvent (imported by src/components/Event/Event.ts)`

When I change the `@Input` into `@Input() data;` there is no problem.

Does anyone know how you can define the type of an `@Input` when using AoT?

See also https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/interface-does-not-export-bundle-dev-failed/66225